# hazelcast storeall not getting invoked

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using hazelcast (v2.1.3) - in the storeload for the map, "store" keeps getting invoked instead of "store all" (even though the write delay seconds flag is greater than 0):

```
<map-store enabled="true">
<class-name>test.test.abcMap</class-name>
<write-delay-seconds>5</write-delay-seconds> 
</map-store>
```

Any useful suggestions to help troubleshoot this would be quite welcome.  I had asynch write behinds working on a different project but cannot seem to get them working right now.  Thanks

**Edit**
After the delay specified in the write-delay-seconds, the store implementation gets invoked (as opposed to the store all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have more than one entry that needs to be stored?

If only one entry in the map has been added or updated, `MapStore.store(key, value)` will be called even if you have write-behind enabled.  `MapStore.storeAll(map)` will only be called if more than one entry needs to be stored.

Here's the relevant code from `com.hazelcast.impl.CMap.runStoreUpdate()` (the member `store` is of type `MapStore`):

```
if (updates.size() == 1) {
    Map.Entry entry = updates.entrySet().iterator().next();
    store.store(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
} else if (updates.size() > 1) {
    store.storeAll(updates);
}
```

The same applies to `MapStore.delete()` and `MapStore.deleteAll()`.

You can see this code in context in the [Hazelcast source](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v2.1.3/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/impl/CMap.java#L968) at Github

Comment: thanks for sharing - I will reconfirm the map size and revert with an update on this post.  +1 for the response!